# Why does the up button have different background to rest of the actionbar

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar

I have been using actionbarsherlock and I have been having problems with setting the background, This is how I have set the background

```
BitmapDrawable actionbar_background =(BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.actionbar);
        actionbar_background.setTileModeY(TileMode.REPEAT);
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(actionbar_background);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

But the problem is that the up button seems to have a shade or tint in the background and it really looks ugly in a real device
this is what I mean:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/35866688/Screen%20Capture.PNG

Can anyone suggest what is the problem

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing `actionbar_background.setTileModeY(TileMode.REPEAT);` seems to solve the problem, the actionbar aldready knows to repeat the image.

Although I am still not sure how setTilemodeY was causing the problem. Anyone with an explnation is welcomed